Pump dot fun Official program ids
Hello I am trying to code a pump.fun bot which buys and sells tokens via js.
I am having trouble coming up with the official program ids. Can someone please help me provide the official program ids for pumpfun?

According to one SDK that I found on GitHub, the program id is 6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P. Looking at the amount of transactions sent to the program on the explorer at https://explorer.solana.com/address/6EF8rrecthR5Dkzon8Nwu78hRvfCKubJ14M5uBEwF6P, I think this might be the correct one!
Reference: https://github.com/rckprtr/pumpdotfun-sdk/blob/78a01ec81037d170643e0c4c3c39f9b6880d3d30/src/pumpfun.ts#L43C21-L43C64
